# How to display milliseconds in Xpage view column?

Tags: xpages

My view column is designed to show ALL time entries and I have verified that it displays "14:56:28:42" in my Notes view.

I'd like to display it in a view column in my viewPanel in Xpages but fails.

```
<xp:viewColumn
    columnName="$2"
    id="viewColumn1"
>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime
            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"
            >
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader
        value="Created"
        id="viewColumnHeader1"
    >
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

It shows zeros (000) for all milliseconds. If I add for instance "z" to the pattern it will display the timezone.

Please advice!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `@Text()` in the Notes view and let it do its work there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to that the notes date time control does not add milliseconds precision to the data (see http://www.jeroensomhorst.eu/uncategorized/dont-forget-the-milliseconds-a-post-about-dates-and-datetime-comparison/). atleast that is what I found out when working with date/time controls.

Comment: That's why you use @text in the view :-)